# Ruby on Rails basic use of RiotGames API (need explanation, solution already found)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, http, parsing

First you must know I'm a total beginner, I'm trying to learn so I almost don't know anything.

On the [basic page of the API](https://developer.riotgames.com/getting-started.html), there is a curl command used as an example to show us how to make requests.

I'm using Ruby on Rails so I used "curl-to-ruby" website to translate it, but it did not work as expected.

I wanted it to show me this :

```
uri = URI.parse("REQUEST_URL")
response = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get(uri))
```

Instead I got this :

```
uri = URI.parse("REQUEST_URL")
response = Net:HTTP.get_response(uri)
```

I don't understand any of this, I thought I wouldn't need to and just use "curl-to-ruby", but apparently I really need to get this.

Would you please try to explain me ?
Or give me links ?
Or matters to read (curl, API, http) ?

Thank you very much, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

It's because that command doesn't return just the content, it returns the whole HTTP response object including headers and body. You need to extract the response body and parse that using JSON.parse(), e.g.

```
JSON.parse(response.body)
```

See documentation here: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-get_response

(Also, there is nothing in the cURL command which would hint to the converter that the content-type of the response was expected to be JSON (e.g. perhaps an "accepts" header or something), so even if it were able to produce extra code adding the JSON.parse part, it has no way of knowing that it would be appropriate to do so in this case.)